# How to remove default style of button

Tags: html, css

I've created a button and added CSS on to but the outcome isn't the expected outcome.
[image]

This is my HTML code

```css
.button{
  /* centre the button  */
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* adding colour and style */
  background-color: #008CBA; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  /* text-decoration: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = button>
   <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: your css selector should be `.button button` because you are targeting the button element inside of the button class

Comment: overall also a really messy code. No need for a prefix to use translate. Which also is not necessary at all. as you can center it with text-align on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.button button {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 300ms;
}

button:hover {
  background: #007095;
}
```

```html
<div class = button>
  <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by styling your button element not the button class of another element as the following code

```
button{
  /* centre the button  */
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* adding colour and style */
    background-color: #008CBA; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Or if you insist to use another container div which i don't recommend you can remove the button element properties.

If this is the case you could add the following code to your CSS

```
button{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
button:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to your button element and style as you wish.

```css
.btn {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: lightgreen;
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">My Button</button>
```